# Override mvc.Controller.template()

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I would like to override the method template() for separate mobile views and desktop views.
I have created a new method (isMobile()) in the mvc.Controller to know if the visitor uses a mobile or not.

isMobile() return true if it's a mobile.

In template(), I call isMobile() and if return me true I change the path.

Normally this should work. But no. Even if I destroy the template method the application work anyway.

I were trying to stop and restart the app but the app still work.

Thanks

Edit:
Ok I think I need to know how can I recompile the play libs to save  my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to recompile your changes to the framework core code, go to the framework folder and type "ant".

You can also checkout my fork (update to 1.2.5RC3) at https://github.com/greenlaw110/play.

Add the following code to anyone of your controller:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public static class BootLoader extends Job<Object> {
    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        Controller.registerTemplateNameResolver(new ITemplateNameResolver(){
            @Override
            public String resolveTemplateName(String templateName) {
                // replace the following statement with your user agent detect logic
                return UserAgent.isMobile() ? "mobile/" + templateName : templateName;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure you do `git checkout 1.2.x` after you cloned my fork, and then `cd framework;ant` to compile.

Comment: tanks for your help.  I can't use your fork for security reason.